# Validate all JSON requests in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I am making a registration function with a RegisterRequest request class which should validate the request:

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
  //
}
```

The request validation (RegisterRequest) looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Api\User;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class RegisterRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // TODO: should secure this.
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        ];
    }
}
```

But I get the error that name and email are missing, I think this is because the request is send in JSON. How can I make this request validate the JSON input I am giving? Thanks in advance.

The way I am making the request:

```
handleSubmit (data) {
      // Register User
      this.$http
        .post('/api/user/register', data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          // Clear form
          // Show snackbar
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
        .finally(
          // Update items in DataTable
          console.log(data)
        )
    }
```

When I `console.log(data);` it shows me this:

```
{"name":"asdsfsdf","email":"sdfsfd@sdfs.com"}
```

when I try to validate like this:

```
       $validator = Validator::make($request->json()->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        ]);
```

It works, but I want to separate this logic from the controller.

Comment: Whether it's JSON or not, the request should pass still. Press F12 in your browser and check the request to see if data is actually sent to the server

Comment: When I dd() the $request I get this: `array:1 [
  "{"name":"sdfsafsa","email":"fdsafa@sdfs_com"}" => null
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by using the `prepareForValidation` method (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#prepare-input-for-validation):

```
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'name' => $this->json('name'),
            'email' => $this->json('email')
        ]);
    }
```

The rules function now successfully validates the JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're not sending the data correctly to the server --- you're sending it as an array key. In your AJAX/request call, send data as following (I'm using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library as demo, but the schema can be applied in jquery or other js tools as well):

```
axios.post('/link/to/web/route', {
    name: 'my name',
    email: 'my email',
}).then(response=>{
    alert('Data sent with success!')
}).catch(error=>{
    alert('Error has occurred. Please check browser console');
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: Even when I use your answer, it says `the name field is required` and `the email field is required`.